# Dependency Management for COBOL

Tags: cobol

Does anything like transitive dependency management exist in the COBOL world?

Is there any kind of repository system for COBOL binaries?

Comment: Take a look at http://maven-nar.github.io/ Might help...?

Comment: Please add a comment if you downvote the question. I would like to understand how to improve the question.

Comment: Regarding the repository part of your question, which operating system?  For example, on z/OS COBOL (and Assembler, and PL/I) program objects are typically stored in a PDSE.

Comment: Regarding the transitive dependency management part of your question, at a source level, an executable level, or both?

Comment: At the moment COBOL is run in BS2000 (but that may change in the future...). We are looking for a way to manage the dependencies of the executables. The "repository" may be on any operating system. I just wanted to get an idea in which direction I could look.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "COBOL world" in the sense you intend. COBOLs on Linux/Unix/Windows will be one thing, where your question may make sense. Outside of that world (of LUW), your question means nothing. You will have user-written programs and some run-time routines. These will be in different "libraries". End of story, nothing else. Remember also that COBOL outside of that world is compiled, as in really compiled. To machine-code. Hardware-specific machine-code. Unless you get some particularly technical person with specific Burroughs experience, you're going nowhere with binaries.

Comment: On the other hand, subject to Burroughs Extensions to COBOL (of which I have no clue, but I think there are docs "out there") the code will likely compile on any COBOL compiler on any hardware and run as expected. Where sub-programs are used, you'll need to compile those also, and if you'll possibly need a bit of "linking" jiggery-pokery, but it won't be directly to do with the COBOL code.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "dependency management", please, and how it is relevant to COBOL executable programs (as opposed to COBOL source code)?

Comment: @JFMeier:  Sobisch defined "dependency management" in his answer, and I think I pointed to a tool that does it.  Would you please provide your own definition, and review the comments on his answer to see if this is the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Simon Sobisch defined dependency management in the way I would also define the term. When I am back in my office, I will have a look at the links. Thank you so far the detailed discussions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for your (very broad but still valid) question would be "NO" as the comments already suggest. For this answer I define "dependency management software" as a software which helps to see what programs and files are needed to run an application (which consists of many COBOL programs [otherwise you won't need a management for this]), ideally versioned [for version N of program X I'd need the programs Y and Z in the version M, together with files A and B).

What makes a working dependency system for COBOL hard is that you would have an easy to track source level dependency (consisting only of source and copy books) and a runtime dependency which you cannot track:

`CALL "SOMEMODULE"` (more or less static calls) can be easily tracked, but often you'll see `CALL somemodule` (highly dynamic calls where the actual module name is stored in a variable). For the later one you'd have to check for all the possible values the variable can get (sometimes only one simple `MOVE "PROG"` directly before the `CALL`, sometimes the variable will be changed by sub-programs or even be taken from a file/DB/whatever).
The second dependency you normally have are files/DB-connections. These are mostly not static like in `ASSIGN to "file1"` but dynamic `ASSIGN TO filename` with the same issues like you have with the dynamic program calls.

Therefore you often do not have a real dependency management (as defined above) but only have versioned "snapshots" of [compiled] COBOL programs and files with everything packed together that (should) work.

In the "Windows/Unix world" you have them placed in an archive, a backup procedure (maybe incremental) or a version management which works for binaries.

Comment: You appear to define dependency management as being related to tracking what a COBOL program "touches".   You note that "static" references (to externally called subprograms, to external files using hardwired constants) are possible but that "dynamic" references (using computed values) are also possible.   You imply that tracking the latter is harder (yes, it is but it is doable in a practical way).  I don't understand the "therefore" clause; it sounds like you are packing a working set of binaries together as "dependency management".  Do I have that right?

Comment: ... that seems to have the strange property that all the *programs* you might need to run an application are bundled together, but not all the programs *and files*, yet you clearly emphasized (dynamic) dependency on files.  (Call me puzzled).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've edited the answer and hope it is more clear now.
And "doable in a practical way" mostly means to add some information manually (or add extra steps like unloading a file and adding this information when "dynamic" called programs get the variable information by reading a file).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and especially the definition.   Regarding "doable in a practical way":  program analysis technology in fact can provide a practical answer, by tracing what values a variable might take. A simple case is the *MOVE "PROG" directly before the CALL*.  There are, agreed, more complex cases, and there are cases where an analyzer (and even a human) cannot figure it out [thank you Alan Turing]; in these cases one can make a conservative ("safe") guess that any module with the same procedure argument structure is a potential callee. ...

Comment: .... One can augment that with additional information from JCL, and in the worst case, by manual specification.   One can similarly do this for dynamic file bindings, using additional information such as the actual binding provided by JCL, or using "matching record structure" as obtained from system metadata and/or record structure known to be associated with a file, as discovered by inspecting other programs in application.   Bottom line: a tool can automate the capture of dependency information across a set of code.  Doing this for multiple versions is just doing it for each version's code.

Comment: Now...  with that background, as to whether the answer to the question is *NO*: is this (my company's) example tool not exactly a dependency management tool?  http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Architecture/ComponentConnectivity.html  [It uses most of the static and dynamic analysis techniques I've mentioned, and yes it was a hard tool to build].

Comment: @IraBaxter: the link you've provided doesn't show a sample output and it isn't clear if "the tool" can be invoked like "give me all dependencies on program/file X", therefore I cannot say if it is or not.

Comment: Well, follow the links to examples: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Architecture/Example/ComponentConnectivityExampleWithDiscussion.html and http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Architecture/Example/Compilation_Unit_P0791.cbl_6.html

Comment: This looks good but it still doesn't show if you can see in a complex example where program X is called from and which calls are done (in the second, third, ... hierarchy).
Nonetheless I suggest to add a comment showing what you have and ask the op if this is what he looks for.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at some of the IBM tools -- Rational Asset Manager for binaries and Websphere Asset Analyzer for dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not related for `Cobol` but to `BS2000` (your operating system) because you work only with binaries.

For C++ you can find a lot of libraries (on Linux, Windows, BS2000) that you can import into your system and build (if possible) and put in a LMS librairies as element of L type (on BS2000).

In the past (2005), I have written a new editor for `BS2000` more powerful than `EDT` (BS2000 Siemens Editor) in which I have add `Regex` features in including `PCRE` library.

I have donwload `PCRE` sources on `BS2000` and I have migrated his codes so that all modules are fully working.

When this has been done, I have put binaries in a library named `BREGEX.B.LMSLIB` with same version number than `PCRE` library.

Now, everytime I want to use `Regex` in C++ program but also in a COBOL program, I include this module in `BINDER` script (link editor on BS2000 replacing TSOSLNK) script using a `//RESOLVE-MODULES` or `//INCLUDE-LIBRARY` BINDER command.

If this `L` module need others modules from others libraries, I must explicitely include these modules in my `BINDER` script.

Since link edition is done completely by a `BS2000` procedure (script in BS2000) you can mix `BINDER` commands and `BS2000` variable to include all dependencies.

Example:

```
/START-BINDER
//INCLUDE-MODULE <main-program-name>
//RESOLVE-LIBRARY BREGEX.B.LMSLIB
//RESOLVE-LIBRARY LOGGING-LIBRARY-FOR-BREGEX
//RESOLVE-LIBRARY DEPENDENCY-LIBRARY-2-FOR-BREGEX
//END
```

or using `BS2000` 'scripting' variable

```
/INCLUDE-PROCEDURE INIT-BINDER-SCRIPTING-VARIABLE

/START-BINDER
//INCLUDE-MODULE <main-program-name>
/BREAK
/&(RESOLVE-BREGEX)
/RESOLVE
//END
```

PS: I'm answering without having some examples because I'm in holiday but if somebody is asking some examples (using comments), I can find them on my home PC and give more information.

For information, I don't program on BS2000 since more than 12 years and I have kept sources of my Editor !